# How to autocomplete single-double quotes, parentheses, etc in VIM editor?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I need that everytime a write a single or double quote, parentheses, curly braces, square braces... automatically vim should create the closing one and put the cursor inside in order to continue editing easily. I noted that most editor do that.

I need this working for each programing language. PHP, JS, JQUERY, HTML, CSS... but without using a snippet, because snippets should need a shorcut or keymap to do that (not productive). I need this autocompletition works automatically after hit " key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins available such as delimitMate that provide this capability. Or, you can create your own mappings. A larger list of plugins, and a detailed discussion of potential mappings, can be found here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters; in general mappings are similar to:

```
inoremap        (  ()<Left>
inoremap <expr> )  strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == ")" ? "\<Right>" : ")"
```

However, currently (as of Vim 7.4.781) such mappings, and any plugin you install, will break undo/redo/repeat, so that it takes two undo steps to remove the text you entered: 1 to remove inside parentheses, one to remove the parentheses themselves. There is a patch available to fix this, if you are comfortable compiling your own Vim: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/gBumYDSEJoo/discussion

Comment: delimitMate did the work! - Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install plug-in for this. [This](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is an example plug-in. Its easier to use [Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) than any other editor.Its easy and light weight.

Comment: Does You-Complete-Me do bracket completion? I thought it was code completion.